# how to bring up failed container

Tags: docker

have a container that failed after a long setup and i want to log in (exec bash) at that point instead of executing the slow setup again. Is there any way?

The container is a left over from a `docker build` process, it is still the `FROM ... AS builder` stage.

if i try to start it, it will fail right away.

```
$ docker start -ai 3d35a7f7a7b4  
/bin/sh: mvn: command not found
```

trying to exec anything right away doesn't work either

```
$ docker start 3d35a7f7a7b4 & docker exec 3d35a7f7a7b4 -it /bin/sh
[1] 403273
3d35a7f7a7b4
unable to upgrade to tcp, received 500
[1]+  Done                    docker start 3d35a7f7a7b4
```

more info:

```
$ docker inspect 3d35a7f7a7b4
[
    {
        "Id": "3d35a7f7a7b4018ebbbd9aa59356714d7fed291a43752cbcb86dd852c946cc1e",
        "Created": "2022-07-06T23:56:37.001004587Z",
        "Path": "/bin/sh",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "mvn --version"
      ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 127,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-07-07T00:02:35.755444447Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2022-07-07T00:02:35.75741167Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:4819e2469963fdf531ec5bce5401b7ae7d28cd403528c0109512b5170ef61752",
...
```

Comment: I would also suggest trying the restart command before this. https://www.thorsten-hans.com/how-to-run-commands-in-stopped-docker-containers/

Comment: otherwise, just remove the container and then start a new one off the same image

Answer (score 1):

this is not an optimal answer. Here just for documentation (and for people to vote up if it is the best one can do with docker)

`docker run` can be used on the image of the stopped container, and you can pass the CMD parameter right away. But any other peculiarity of the stopped container will also have to be repeated. e.g. network.

for the example on the question:

```
host$ docker run -it sha256:4819e2469963fdf531ec5bce5401b7ae7d28cd403528c0109512b5170ef61752 /bin/bash
container# _
```

Comment: This is actually pretty much exactly what I'd recommend FWIW.  In a Compose setup, `docker-compose run the-container /bin/bash` will take most of the settings from the `docker-compose.yml` file.  Images with `ENTRYPOINT` declarations that ignore their `CMD` will be harder to debug this way.

Comment: good point about composer. my case was a half-way docker build command. CMD was the RUN line where it crashed, so it would crash always. i was still in the intermediate step which would then later be used in `COPY --from=...` steps... there was not even a semblance of name to that container.